# Drupal config error "module.settings" depends on the module that will not be installed after import

Tags: 8

I'm having this error on Travis Build.  I can't go pass this error.  I've been removing `dblog` from the list of config and also delete from my localhost database before I export `drush cex sync -y`

```
 The import failed due to the following reasons:                              
  Configuration <em class="placeholder">dblog.settings</em> depends on the <e  
  m class="placeholder">Database Logging</em> module that will not be install  
  ed after import.                                                             
  Configuration <em class="placeholder">views.view.watchdog</em> depends on t  
  he <em class="placeholder">Database Logging</em> module that will not be in  
  stalled after import. '
```

What else should I try to solve this problem?

Comment: I wonder if by now you found a solution for it? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This usually happens when the module isn't enabled in `core.extension.yml` but you are trying to import the config for that module.

It can usually be fixed by adding it to `core.extension.yml`
E.g.

```
  dblog: 0
```

Note that the "zero" indicates the "weight" of the module, and does *not* indicate a 0/1 enabled/disabled boolean.

Comment: Answer is valid for the error I had for syslog too: `The import failed due to the following reasons: Configuration syslog.settings depends on the Syslog module that will not be installed after import.`

Comment: Having this issue where THEME.settings cannot be imported because THEME "module" is not installed. The module exists in core.extension.yml  Very weird.  :(